# Compare last modify date/time of a file to current date/time?

Tags: php

How can I Delete file if file older than current date(today)

```
step 1 : Check file last modification date
step 2 : If file date older than Today Date than Delete file
step 3 : Else do nothing
```

**NOTE** : I Don't want to delete file older than 24 hours ( I only want to delete older than current date)

Comment: Do you specifically want a php answer? `find . -daystart -mtime +0 -exec rm {} \;` will remove all files in the current folder that match your requirements.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yes only in PHP

Comment: @Melody Hi Melody, people sometimes downvote if they feel that someone asking a question hasn't researched the answer for themselves first. It may be that you have tried some solutions that didn't work but in that case it's good to post those too so that the community can help with what you have so far. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has some good topics on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a pure PHP answer, you want something like the following:

```
function deleteOldFile($file) {
    $mdate = date("Ymd", filemtime($file));
    $date  = date("Ymd");
    if ($mdate < $date) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```